# PyDev encoding error in debug after update

Tags: unicode, encoding, pydev

We recently upgraded to Eclipse 4.4 / PyDev 3.8 from Eclipse 4.2 / PyDev 2.7. Unfortunately, we now get this error when we run our code as Debug:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.8.0.201409251235\pysrc\pydevd.py",
>   line 2183, in 
>       globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)   File "C:\Programs\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.8.0.201409251235\pysrc\pydevd.py",
>   line 1622, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "C:\Mercurial\ABC\tools\foo.pyc", line
>   1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf3' in file
>   C:\Mercurial\ABC\tools\foo.pyc on line 1, but no
>   encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for
>   details

The same code works fine when run as a normal Python Run, and it worked fine in both Run and Debug on the older version of Eclipse/PyDev.

From what I've found on Stack Overflow and online, the standard solution when you get this error is to add "# coding = utf-8" to the top of the file in question. However, we don't have control of "foo.pyc" - there's no way for us to modify this file. Is there anything else we can try?

The python version is 2.7.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the original line breaks in the error message. I tried to edit, and I see "> " prefixes, but I'm not sure where the original line breaks are. In StackOverflow, use four space characters at the start of each line to get literal (or "code") formatting.