# Pydev 3.8 or 3.9 requires utf-8 encoding to be manually set in Python 3 code: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydev

Running this code in Python 3.4 from Python shell works just fine:

```
from csv import reader

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = "valid.csv"

    with open(filename) as f:
        csvreader = reader(f)
        for keyword in csvreader:
            kw = keyword[0]
```

However, running it in Eclipse with Pydev 3.8 or 3.9 fails:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 64416)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2183, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1622, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "/Users/antoinebrunel/src/test_pydev/test_pydev/test_pydev.py", line 14, in <module>
    for keyword in csvreader:
  File "/Users/antoinebrunel/.virtualenvs/seo3/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In order for the code to run, replace:

```
with open(filename, mode='rt') as f:
```

with:

```
with open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Note 1: The file *valid.csv* contains any character with accent, for example:

```
à
```

Note 2: In Eclipse preferences > workspace, text file encoding is set to utf-8

Reference
[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744231/pydev-encoding-error-in-debug-after-update) may be related

Comment: Are you saying you already solved this? If so, put the answer part in a *answer post* below. Or is there still an actual question left here?

Comment: This is still a question, it is not solved yet, a ticket #497 was also opened on [Pydev Brainwy tracker](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/) and apparently this will be resolved for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation:

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. **The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns)**, but any encoding supported by Python can be used.

Emphasis mine. You should not rely on the default encoding; evidently the PyDev environment has been set to a locale where ASCII is the default codec.

If you know up front that your CSV is encoded to UTF-8, explicitly set the codec when opening the file, and do not assume that the system on which you are running this has been configured with UTF-8 as the preferred text data codec.

Comment: 1- Maybe it's better to explicitly set encoding. However, in Eclipse, if the workspace text encoding setting is defined to utf-8, this setting should be used instead of ascii ...
2- Why does it fail in Eclipse and not when running it in Python or in python shell?

Comment: @antoinet: the workspace text encoding has nothing do to with the default locale in Python code. What system are you running this on (what OS?). Clearly Eclipse is altering the environment; on POSIX systems for example it depends on the `LANG` variable what locale is being picked.

Comment: @MartinPieters I'm using OSX 10.9.5. Either Pydev should use the same encoding as the Python interpreter, or there should be a setting in Eclipse to define the default encoding within pydev. Pydev developers are planning to resolve it by the next release (Ticket #497). Best!

Comment: @antoinet: yes, Pydev should probably echo your system wide settings. Take into account though that the default can be changed *from shell to shell too*. Your code should never rely on the default, really.